# insert two nodes in neo4j and estimate the time then insert 4 nodes and estimate the time

Tags: neo4j

Can somebody please give something about how to insert two nodes in neo4j and estimate the time then insert 4 nodes and estimate the time then 8 ,16,32 and so on until 1024 nodes.

Comment: By estimate do you need the time it takes really ? Also, what programming language do you use ?

Comment: i use cypher query language . all what i need to know the time of entering two nods at once ,then the execution time of entering 4 nodes at once  and so on until 1024 .also how to insert 1024 nodes at once?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example in PHP, idea is the same in any programming language :

```
$query = 'UNWIND range(1,{max}) as i CREATE (n:Node {v:i})';
$max = 2;
do {
    $s = microtime(true);
    $client->run($query, ['max' => $max]);
    echo sprintf('query took %f ms', microtime(true) - $s) . PHP_EOL;
    $max *= 2;
} while($max <= 1024);
```

Which will return :

```
query took 0.020220 ms
query took 0.009002 ms
query took 0.011413 ms
query took 0.014552 ms
query took 0.012378 ms
query took 0.021977 ms
query took 0.032880 ms
query took 0.019982 ms
query took 0.045166 ms
query took 0.046428 ms
```